# How to use a common cursor in PLSQL script for multiple tables in same definition

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

There are 4 table in a DB as A, B, C and D. That tables has exact same structure.
I need to use same set of procedures to process those table and generate a single file

several utility procedures are available in my design i need to pass a row as a parameter for those procedure.

What is best way to implement a PLSQL script for that purpose ?

Please provide a high level overview?

Note:
my basic problem is use a common cursor and a common rowtype for this.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Native Dynamic SQL it's an easy way to query any table using fixed set of parameters and result variables (including records):

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select ... from ' || table_name || ' where ....' 
    USING in_par_1, in_par2, OUT out_par_1, ...;

OPEN <cursor> FOR 'select ... from ' || table_name || ' where ....' 
    using ...;
LOOP
    FETCH <cursor> INTO ...;
    EXIT WHEN <cursor>%NOTFOUND;
    ...
END LOOP
```

(and others ways to dynamic data exchange are provided).

The biggest NDS problem is the lack of compile-time error checks, so it might be not easy to support it and there is a risk to break something and don't even notice that.

In your case one good trick can be used:

1. create a View which aggregates all data and marks its data source
2. create only one procedures set which depends on common data structure (the view) and data source ID (procedure's parameter).

The sample listing:

```
create or replace view view_abcd as
    select 'a' as data_type, a.* from a
    union
    select 'b', b.* from b
    union
    select 'c', c.* from c
    union
    select 'd', d.* from d;

... procedure/function process_data( dataType ) ...
select .... from view_abcd v where v.data_type = dataType and ...
```